# Counterexample of a basis of topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose $\mathcal C$ is a collection of open sets in $X$ such that

(1) Each $C\in\mathcal C$ is nonempty, and $\mathcal C$ covers $X$,

(2) for any nonempty open set $U\subset X$, there is some $C\in\mathcal C$ such that $C\subset U$.

Is $\mathcal C$ a basis for the topological space? If not, can you find a counterexample?

I came up with this question myself, and I speculate that the answer is no, but I can't find any proper counterexample. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Such a $\mathcal C$ is usually called $\pi$-base (without requiring that it actually covers the space, but this is not essential) and the smallest (infinite) cardinality of such a $\mathcal C$ is called $\pi$-weight.

Comment: $\mathcal C := \{U: \emptyset \neq U$ open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $0 \notin U \} \cup \{\mathbb{R}\}$ is another example of a $\pi$-base, which is not a base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a counterexample myself.

Let $\mathbb R_\ell$ be the lower limit topology on real numbers. Then the set $\mathcal C$ of all open intervals satisfy the condition: it covers $\mathbb R$, and any open set $[a,b)$ obviously contains an open interval. But $\mathcal C$ obviously does not form a basis.

Answer (score 4):

Take $\cal C$ to be $\{\emptyset, X\}$. Certainly it covers the whole space $X$, and for any $U$ open in $X$, we have $\emptyset \subseteq U$ (because this is true for any set $U$!). And certainly both of these sets in $\cal C$ are open in the original topology (call it $\cal T$).

But this $\cal C$ is not a base for $\cal T$ if $\cal T$ is larger than $\cal C$.

Comment: Your wording is a little unclear. I believe you mean to say that those two sets provide a counter-example as long as the topology is not the indiscrete topology. But saying that $X$ has the indiscrete topology and further discussing an original topology is confusing.

Comment: Yes, thanks @John, the fact that $\cal C$ is also a topology is not actually relevant. Edited!

Comment: Thanks @Hew. I meant the collection C to consist only of non empty sets, otherwise the case is trivial.

Comment: @Zhuo, I see. There is still a small problem though: if you want condition (2) to apply to any open set $U$, it must in particular apply to $\emptyset$, which forces you to include $\emptyset$ in $\cal C$. Probably (2) should say "for any _nonempty_ open set..."

Comment: @Hew Yes ,you're right. I have edited my question. I also came up with a counterexample (see below).